# C# Traverse tree and find all unique hierarchy chains from root to leaf

Tags: c#, data-structures, tree

I am working on a tree problem and not able to figure out how to solve the problem at hand. I've googled and also checked on SO, but could not find
a suitable approach, so seeking help from the expert community.

Problem is this:

There is a class 'Person', defined like below. The class traces the hierarchy of a given Person.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Now the hierarchy of a Person 'A' is defined like this:

```
Person A = new Person()
{
    Name = "A",
    Children = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person()
        {
            Name = "B",
            Children = new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person()
                {
                    Name = "E",
                    Children = null
                },
                new Person()
                {
                    Name = "F",
                    Children = new List<Person>()
                    {
                        new Person()
                        {
                            Name = "H",
                            Children = null
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        new Person()
        {
            Name = "C",
            Children = new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person()
                {
                    Name = "G",
                    Children = null
                }
            }
        },

        new Person()
        {
            Name = "D",
            Children = null
        }
    }
};
```

So Person 'A' has 3 children (B,C,D).
'B' has 2 children (E,F),
'F' has 1 child (H),
'C' has 1 child (G),
'D' has no child.

And this class can model any person anywhere.
Now given another class where a given person can have only one child, like so:

```
public class PersonWithOneChildMax
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PersonWithOneChildMax Child { get; set; }
}
```

How can I get hierarchy chains for Person 'A' earlier in terms of objects of 'PersonWithOneChildMax'?
So final result will be a list of 'PersonWithOneChildMax' and will contain 4 objects for the example above. Those 4 objects will be:

```
PersonWithOneChildMax firstChain = new PersonWithOneChildMax()
{
    Name = "A",
    Child = new PersonWithOneChildMax()
    {
        Name = "B",
        Child = new PersonWithOneChildMax()
        {
            Name = "E",
            Child = null
        }
    }
};

PersonWithOneChildMax secondChain = new PersonWithOneChildMax()
{
    Name = "A",
    Child = new PersonWithOneChildMax()
    {
        Name = "B",
        Child = new PersonWithOneChildMax()
        {
            Name = "F",
            Child = new PersonWithOneChildMax()
            {
                Name = "H",
                Child = null
            }
        }
    }
};

PersonWithOneChildMax thirdChain = new PersonWithOneChildMax()
{
    Name = "A",
    Child = new PersonWithOneChildMax()
    {
        Name = "C",
        Child = new PersonWithOneChildMax()
        {
            Name = "G",
            Child = null
        }
    }
};

PersonWithOneChildMax fourthChain = new PersonWithOneChildMax()
{
    Name = "A",
    Child = new PersonWithOneChildMax()
    {
        Name = "D",
        Child = null
    }
};
```

So in short, I am looking for a way to get all possible hierarchies for Person A:

```
A->B->E  
A->B->F->H  
A->C->G  
A->D
```

How can I get the final result which will be a list of objects of type 'PersonWithOneChildMax' and will contain 4 objects defined above- 'firstChain',
'secondChain', 'thirdChain' and 'fourthChain' ?

Apologies for the very long question.

Comment: I understand that your first initial class can hold as many children as it wants. What is unclear is your mechanic for your 'OneMaxChild' concept that you've presented. You'd like a method that could receive ClassOne and generate a certain number of instances of Class2 with the logic you've provided ?

Comment: Yes, 'Person' class can have any number of nested children. Final result should contain a list of objects of class 'PersonWithOneChildMax' and the number of objects of type 'PersonWithOneChildMax'  in the final list should traverse all unique relationship chains from root to node.

Comment: How is that different from ‘DFS’ in dynamic way? (Filtering for some specific type) ?

Comment: Still new to trees, but per my understanding 'Depth First Traversal' will visit all the nested children of Person 'A' and will print them in a depth first fashion. However, for the problem at hand, requirement is to get all relationship hierarchies for Person 'A' (there are 4 unique hierarchies in the example given above as explained) and each hierarchy should be obtained in the form of object of class 'PersonWithOneChildMax'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So walk the tree in depth-first order, keeping a list of the nodes you've visited along the way. Whenever you reach a leaf node (a person with no children), create a hierarchy and add it to the result list.

I haven't tested this, but the basic idea is:

```
public List<PersonWithOneChildMax> BuildFromPersonList(List<Person> people)
{
    var ancestors = new List<Person>();
    var result = new List<PersonWithOneChildMax>();
    foreach (var person in people)
    {
        BuildDescendants(person, ancestors, result);
    }
    return result;
}

private void BuildDescendants(Person person, List<Person> ancestors, List<PersonWithOneChildMax> result)
{
    if (person.Children == null || person.Children.Count == 0)
    {
        var newPerson = new PersonWithOneChildMax {Name = person.Name, Child = null};
        // build the hierarchy backwards
        for (var i = ancestors.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            newPerson = new PersonWithOneChildMax {Name = ancestors[i].Name, Child = newPerson};
        }
        result.Add(newPerson);
    }
    else
    {
        ancestors.Add(person);
        foreach (var child in person.Children)
        {
            BuildDescendants(child, ancestors, result);
        }
        ancestors.RemoveAt(ancestors.Count-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jim. This is exactly what I was looking for. Just had to make 2 edits to make it compilable and not crash at runtime:  return type 'void' of method 'BuildDescendants' and 'null' check in 'if' block: if (person.Children == null || person.Children.Count == 0)

Comment: @learner: Glad it helped you out. Thanks for the corrections.